# Itemize with table-like alignment

Tags: beamer, equations, horizontal-alignment, itemize

I often want to show an equation and start below a list with descriptions of the terms. Each item consists of two parts. First, the symbol and, second, a short explanation. See below

[image: Output]

I think it would look much nicer if these two parts were separated like in a table so that the second part starts for each item at the same place. Here is a sketch of how the alignment should look like

[image: Align]

This is done with table which omits two nice features of itemize. To have the bullets and the alignment left-indented. Also, the table messes up when I have more complicated descriptions, for example a formula.

Anybody knows how I could accomplish that better?

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Equation}
    \begin{equation}
        Z = M \cdot aX + \int_0^\infty U dU
    \end{equation}
    
    \medskip

    \begin{itemize}
        \item $Z$ : blablalvsaf
        \item $ M \cdot aX$:a ghewuhgewg
        \item $ \int_0^\infty U dU$: we WERGgw   EG
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add a sketch how the result should look like?

Comment: added a picture of the alignment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add things like the itemization triangle to a table:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Equation}
    \begin{equation}
        Z = M \cdot aX + \int_0^\infty U dU
    \end{equation}
    
    \medskip

    \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={
        @{}
        Q[
          mode=dmath,
          preto={\hspace*{\leftmargini}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}\hspace*{\itemsep}},
          appto={:}
         ]
        X
        @{}
      }
    }
         Z & blablalvsaf\\
         M \cdot aX &a ghewuhgewg\\
         \int_0^\infty U dU &we WERGgw   EG
    \end{tblr}
    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]